# Understanding specific regex

Tags: regex

So I have a regex looking like this:

```
('0'|['0'‐'9']+'.'['0'‐'9' 'a'‐'f']*)
```

I am trying to understand it, is this correct:

The imput must start with either a 0 or a number between 0-9, then have a dot and then again contain numbers or letters. A little confused about the star in the end, does it mean it can be mixed?

What if I enter:

1. 'c0ffee.0730'
2. '0'
3. '1'
4. '0830.c0ffee'
5. '09ea67.'

Help understanding this would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please give some contextual information: specifically the environment and programming language?

In a generic context, the expression would look like this:

```
(0|[0‐9]+.[0‐9 a‐f]*)
```

- The parentheses `()` define group. There is only one group.
- The pipe `|` means "or": this *or* that.
- The brackets `[]` define a character set.

  - Within brackets `-` can be used to define a range of numbers or letters. So, `[0-9]` means any number character between 0 and 9.
  - Brackets can contain multiple ranges and individual characters. So, `[0-9 a-f]` means a number between 0 and 9, a space, or a letter between a and f. It is the same as writing `[0123456789 abcdef]`
- The period `.` means "any character"—that is, any *one* character.
- The asterisk `*` means "zero or more."

  - If `*` follows a single character, it means "zero or more of this character."
  - If `*` follows brackets `[]`, then it means "zero or more any character in this set."
  - If `*` follows a group `()`, then it means "zero or more of this group."

So the expression will match

**EITHER**

- the number `0`

**OR**

- a string with

  - 1 or more numbers
  - followed by any character
  - followed by 0 more letters, numbers, or spaces

Answer (score 0):

regex101 is your friend as it breaks down the regex  and every character is explained. I created this link for your regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/fG4hA6/2)

The plus and the star are *Quantifiers* which are used to specify how many instances of the group you would like to find in the searched pattern.